# Ô que ma quille éclate ! Ô que j'aille à la mer !

Tags: sens, poésie

C'est un vers que j'ai rencontré dans le poème *Le bateau ivre* d'Arthur Rimbaud:

> Mais, vrai, j'ai trop pleuré ! Les Aubes sont navrantes.
>   Toute lune est atroce et tout soleil amer :
>   L'âcre amour m'a gonflé de torpeurs enivrantes.
>   **Ô que ma quille éclate ! Ô que j'aille à la mer !**

J'ai des problèmes avec :

> *Ô que ma quille éclate ! Ô que j'aille à la mer !*

Je comprends que le bateau a pleuré, il a pleuré car il avait voyagé si longtemps et en ce moment-là l'Europe lui manquait.

Puis je comprends *Ô que ma quille éclate !*, ça veut dire qu'il voulait trouver un golfe quelconque, il voulait sentir la terre.

Mais pourquoi *Ô que j'aille à la mer !* ?  Est-ce que ça ne veut pas dire qu'il voulait voyager encore ? C'est bien contraire à la phrase précédente.

J'ai une hypothèse. Peut-être qu'il se trouvait dans l'océan, et il cherchait une mer, car elle est plus petite et plus proche de la terre. Mais j'en doute.

Voilà le [texte complet](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/arthur_rimbaud/le_bateau_ivre.html).  Pourriez-vous m'expliquer les pensées de ce bateau ?

Comment: J'ai un peu corrigé le texte de la question.  Une erreur intéressante qui amène à réfléchir à la différence entre « j'en doute » et « je m'en doute », ça ne doit pas être évident pour un non francophone.

Comment: Oui, merci ! Je connais la différence, mais cette fois je n'y ai pas fait attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L'expression « aller à la mer » aurait pu être ambiguë et comprise dans un autre contexte comme signifiant « aller en mer », mais le bateau étant déjà en mer, il n'y a qu'une seule interprétation possible : il souhaite couler.
Cela est confirmé par l’analyse du poème.

Le bateau c'est l'allégorie du poète. Le thème dominant de ce poème est la rupture.

- Rupture politique : [il a été écrit pendant l'été de 1871 au lendemain de la défaite de la Commune](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commune_de_Paris_(1871)), événement qui a [profondément marqué Rimbaud](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rimbaud#Paris_sous_la_Commune). Le dernier vers du poème y fait directement allusion : « les yeux horribles des pontons »  ce sont les yeux des communards emprisonnés dans [les pontons](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponton_prison_flottante#Dans_la_litt.C3.A9rature).
- Rupture entre l'enfance et le passage à l'âge adulte : Rimbaud a 17 ans quand il écrit ce poème, il est secoué par les événements de 1871 qui le font passer à l'âge adulte.

Le bateau de Rimbaud est ivre, secoué, et ceci se traduit  dans les images qui se succèdent et dans l'écriture même du poème, vocabulaire et construction.
Il est ivre, ballotté entre l'ancrage au port (« que ma quille éclate »)
et la disparation dans les flots (« que j'aille à la mer »).
 C'est le poète partagé entre l'appel de l'aventure et l'envie de suicide après les événements de l'hiver-printemps 1871 et la défaite de la Commune.

Il existe de nombreuses études de ce poème.  Un spécialiste de Rimbaud, Alain Rabardel, lui consacre [un site](http://abardel.free.fr/index.htm) et on trouvera [beaucoup de détails sur ce poème](http://abardel.free.fr/petite_anthologie/le_bateau_ivre_panorama.htm).
Il ne dit rien sur  *Ô que j'aille à la mer* mais je viens de consulter les notes de l'édition de La Pleïade qui confirme l'interprétation donnée ci-dessus.

Une partie de l'article de Steve Murphy *Logiques du Bateau ivre*, largement cité par Alain Rabardel, [est accessible ici](http://books.google.fr/books?id=B1PtLX7yHxQC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=steve%20murphy%20%22logiques%20du%20bateau%20ivre%22&source=bl&ots=YOaiHmvye1&sig=KU0T_0qwAW6HRTmAMiVwM7NXi5c&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=Rz3jU_jfFOHa0QWT84HYDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=steve%20murphy%20%22logiques%20du%20bateau%20ivre%22&f=false).

Comment: Mille fois merci !

Answer (score 4):

Pour moi la fin de ce poème est bien plus sombre et triste qu'un texte narrant des envies de voyage ;)

C'est pourquoi j'interprête plutôt le "Ô que ma quille éclate!" comme l'envie pour lui de voir littéralement la quille de son bateau éclater. La quille est ce qui stabilise un bateau. Sur un voilier par exemple, c'est ce qui compense la force exercée sur les voiles, et donc empêche le bateau de se retourner.

Ainsi, si sa quille éclate, il se retournera pour finir à la mer et sans doute y sombrer. Et je pense que cette explication correspond bien avec le ton plus sombre et triste de ce paragraphe.

Comment: C'est interessant. Moi, après avoir lu "Je regrette l'Europe aux anciens parapets", je pensais plutôt qu'il voulais finir près d'Europe, qu'il voulait échouer sur un bas-fond dans un golfe ou dans un port, où l'eau n'est pas profonde. Je lisais "Ô que ma quille éclate!" comme "Ô que je trouve la terre!" (parce que sa quille pouvait s'éclater au bas-fond). Merci pour ton explication !

Comment: Mon explication était plus intuitive que prouvée, remercie Laure pour avoir vérifié cette théorie :)

Answer (score 0):

Je partage l'idée des symboles sexuels :
- "âcre amour" qui peut évoquer l'acidité du sexe, encore faut-il y avoir gouté... ;
- "Ô que ma quille éclate" frôle l'évidence ;
- "Ô que j'aille à la mer" et à son humidité...

Answer (score -1):

Bonjour, 
j'y vois une allusion sexuelle des plus évidente.

Comment: C'est original. On peut aller plus loin et y voir une contrepèterie : *L'âcre Amir m'a gonflé de torpeurs enivrantes. Ô que ma couille éclate !*